# How do I get the index 2-4 of a String in each entry of a column?

Tags: python, string, dataframe

I have a column in a dataframe and need for every entry just the index 2-4 of the string.
For example

```
A
AB101CD
AB101CD
AB101CD
```

result:

```
A
101
101
101
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `df.column.apply`

```
import pandas as pd    
a = ['AB101CD','AB101CD','AB101CD']
df = pd.DataFrame(a)
df.columns = ['A']
df.A.apply(lambda x:x[2:5])
```

This gives:

```
0    101
1    101
2    101
Name: A, dtype: object
```

You could set it as column:

```
 df.A = df.A.apply(lambda x:x[2:5])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get a strings substring by using `{string_variable}[{index1}:{index2}]`

```py
str = "AB101CD"

print(str[2:5])
```

output will be "101"

then you can apply this to your list or whatever with a for loop for example:

```py
mylist = ["A",
          "AB101CD",
          "AB101CD",
          "AB101CD"]

list2 = []

for i in mylist:
    #it wont return anything for the first element, "A", so you should define what do you want to do here for non-suitable elements
    
    #print
    print(i[2:5])

    #get into another list
    list2.append(i[2:5])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can slice the column with broadcasting

```
df['A'] = df['A'].str[2:5]
```

Output

```
     A
0  101
1  101
2  101
```